# How to get "bigger-size" user image with Twitter API 1.1?

Tags: twitter, tweets

I'm trying to get last 5 tweets from a person. I did it, but profile picture is not looking normal, resolution is corrupted. like that. !  http://i.hizliresim.com/wLQEJZ.jpg

```
var $twitter = $('#twitter');

    $.getJSON('http://www.demo.net/twitter.php?username=yeniceriozcan&count=5', function(data){
        var total = data.length,
            i = 0;
        $twitter.html(''); // Ã¶nce iÃ§indekini temizle sonra tweetleri yazdÄ±r.
        for ( i; i < total; i++ ){
            var tweet = data[i].text; // tweet
            var date = parseTwitterDate(data[i].created_at); // tarih
            var image = data[i].user.profile_image_url; // profil resmi
            var url = 'https://twitter.com/' + data[i].user.screen_name +'/status/' + data[i].id_str;
            $twitter.append('<div class="tweet"><a target="_blank" href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '" alt="" class="profile-image" />' + tweet + '</a> <span class="tweet-date">(' + date + ')</span></div>');
        }
    });
```

This is my code. I tried to that for to get profile picture,

```
var image = data[i].user.profile_image_url;
```

And also in other tweets file,

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$username.'&count='.$count);

print json_encode($tweets);
```

I used this api.

but I can not view pictures in normal resolutions. How can I fix it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

I found that using bigger still brought the picture back in a relatively small format. Using this answer enables you to resize the image allowing you to have a big image without distortion.

If you want to get the image full size just get rid of the "_normal" completely

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/429221067630972918/ABLBUS9o_normal.jpeg
```

Goes to

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/429221067630972918/ABLBUS9o.jpeg
```

**Note:** The urls in this answer are modified so as to not reflect my twitter details hence why entering them will give you a "no page exists"

Comment: Note that the full size images can be quite large in filesize

Comment: Some images are not available without the size definition like "_normal" or "_bigger". For example https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/481123524329734146/jk4aTqws_normal.png

Answer (score 24):

When you read the url from data[i].user.profile_image_url, replace "_normal" with "_bigger". Here's the explanation from the Twitter docs:

[User Profile Images and Banners](https://dev.twitter.com/basics/user-profile-images-and-banners)

Answer (score 16):

**Update December 22nd 2020**

This is still the case - works.

**Update May 6th 2017**

When you get the user's profile image via *profile_image_url* or *profile_image_url_https* (see [User Profile Images and Banners](https://dev.twitter.com/basics/user-profile-images-and-banners)), try to replace "*_normal*" at the end of the filename with "*_400x400*".

Seems that they are now scaling images down to 400x400 and then delete the original file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Where did you find this dimension `_400x400`? There is no any info about `400x400` in your link

Comment: @Green They don't document it. I linked to the docu to show how their image-urls are structured. I simply figured it out by myself: Just go on your Twitter profile, click on your profile image and copy image address - there you can see it.

Answer (score 12):

In case you still need this questions answered (since none of the previous ones are marked as an accepted answer) this is how I managed to deal with the `Twitter API` image URL sizing:

Grabbing the `URL` from the API will return the "http" and "https" URL's in the following format(s):

**http:**

`http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378812345851234567/Ay2SHEYz_normal.png`

**https:**

`https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378812345851234567/Ay2SHEYz_normal.png`

For whatever reason Twitter decided that a **48x48 png** was good enough. 
If you want the full resolution you need to **remove** the "_normal" tag from either URL, as [angryTurtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2704817/angryturtle) stated above. This will give you the URL of the full size image. Here is quick example work around of accomplishing this:

```
/// remove '_normal' from picture url to get full size
        NSString *TWTRPicStringF = [twitterProfilePictureURLStringN stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_normal" withString:@""];
```

Hopefully this helps you and you can mark one of these as the accepted answer to close the question!

**FYI**: I *also* have modified the URL contents to protect my own Twitter information, explaining the "no page exists" when using one of the provided URL's above.